# How can I use new toaster version in old yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I need to use toaster for delete or add package in Yocto.

But I think my Yocto version is old and that's why I can't modify my Yocto in toaster.

Some of toaster page can modify the image when build by bitbake command. But I don't have it.

Comment: Toaster is supporting yocto version morethan 1.8, Better you can you new yocto version krogoth, morty etc.,

Comment: I know that. But I can't using newest Yocto.